# App crashes when trying to use setImageResource

Tags: java, android

I was building another larger app and at some point I needed to dynamically change images and my app crashed. So, to test functionality I made another really simple app that just displays a picture with code:

```
package com.example.imagetest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pugs);
    }
}
```

> The error reported by Android Studio is: 03-07 11:30:01.146
>   20758-20758/? E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or
>   directory (2) 03-07 11:30:01.284 20758-20758/com.example.imagetest
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper',
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
>   03-07 11:30:01.286 20758-20758/com.example.imagetest E/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets 03-07
>   11:30:01.298 20758-20758/com.example.imagetest E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets 03-07
>   11:30:01.300 20758-20758/com.example.imagetest E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener', referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
>   03-07 11:30:01.306 20758-20758/com.example.imagetest E/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
>   03-07 11:30:01.354 20758-20758/com.example.imagetest E/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>   03-07 11:30:01.396 20758-20758/com.example.imagetest E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imagetest/com.example.imagetest.MainActivity}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f060063

and a lot of other stuff. Here's the weird thing: I changed the picture to another folder "mipmap" (before it was in drawable: res/drawable) and the app doesn't crash! But it doesn't show the image either, just nothing on screen. the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Not sure if the image is important, but it was a really cute picture of 3 pugs(Resolution approx 4k) and I added it to drawable just with copy/paste.

Comment: It said resourceID not found. Please provide where you put that image in

Comment: Maybe image is too big. You can test with a smaller image. BTW, what is the pugs file's extension? png or jpg?

Comment: In between the error code and the XML I wrote where it is: res/drawable. If it is needed to be more specific: /home/krampus/Documents/imageTest/app/src/main/res/drawable-v24  <- and the picture is named pugs.jpg

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the wrong placement of resources(images). You are using a device with **API** below 24 , so resource for **API** **23** and below is null, because they only **API 24** and up.

please put your pugs picture in **drawable** folder not **drawable-v24** , and also don't use a huge image!

Comment: Tried moving the picture to drawable (not drawable -v24) and the error was still there. Changed the picture to a smaller one (actually it's like 400x400) and it works now. It seems the error was mainly the HUGE resolution.

Comment: as advice do never use larger image in android , check this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxzS6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pugs);
```

You need specify which `R` it is in the `import` part.

example:

```
    import com.sample.me.mydraft.R
```